# SQL group join table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I want to display out the record in the format as below. How to I display the format as below ?

```
Branch   Total Payment Total Discount Total Net Payment
A          10,000         2,000          8,000
B          29,190         1,540          27,656
```

Here are my query for the above. Please help me. Thanks.

```
SELECT  TranID, ProjCode,
CASE WHEN IsActive='N' THEN 'Cancellation' ELSE PaymentType END As PaymentType, 
CASE WHEN PaymentType='Withdrawal' THEN 0 ELSE (CASE WHEN IsActive='N' THEN 0 ELSE Sale END) END As Sale ,
CASE WHEN PaymentType='Withdrawal' THEN 0 ELSE (CASE WHEN IsActive='N' THEN 0 ELSE Sale_Before_CutOff END) END As Sale_Before_CutOff ,
CASE WHEN PaymentType='Withdrawal' THEN 0 ELSE (CASE WHEN IsActive='N' THEN 0 ELSE Net END) END As Net ,
CASE WHEN PaymentType='Withdrawal' THEN 0 ELSE (CASE WHEN IsActive='N' THEN 0 ELSE Net_Before_CutOff END) END As Net_Before_CutOff ,
CASE WHEN PaymentType='Withdrawal' THEN Net ELSE 0 END As Withdrawal, 
CASE WHEN PaymentType='Withdrawal' THEN Net_Before_CutOff ELSE 0 END As Withdrawal_Before_CutOff, 
CASE WHEN IsActive='N' THEN Net ELSE 0 END As Cancellation, 
CASE WHEN IsActive='N' THEN Net_Before_CutOff ELSE 0 END As Cancellation_Before_CutOff, 
CASE WHEN IsActive='N' THEN 0 ELSE Discount END As Discount, 
CASE WHEN IsActive='N' THEN 0 ELSE Discount_Before_CutOff END As Discount_Before_CutOff, AdditionalCommission,AdditionalCommission_Before_CutOff, Remark, UserStamp, BusinessDay, 
TranDate, BranchID, StaffCode, IsActive,Quantity
FROM            
(SELECT c.INTERNAL_TRAN_NUM AS TranID, c.PROJECT_CODE AS ProjCode, c.PAYMENT_TYPE AS PaymentType,d.QUANTITY As Quantity, 
CASE WHEN DATEPART(hh,c.TRAN_DATE) > DATEPART(hh, f.CUT_OFF_TIME) THEN c.TOTAL_PAYMENT ELSE 0 END AS Sale, 
CASE WHEN DATEPART(hh, c.TRAN_DATE)<= DATEPART(hh, f.CUT_OFF_TIME) THEN c.TOTAL_PAYMENT ELSE 0 END AS Sale_Before_CutOff, 
CASE WHEN DATEPART(hh, c.TRAN_DATE)> DATEPART(hh, f.CUT_OFF_TIME) THEN c.NET_PAYMENT ELSE 0 END AS Net, 
CASE WHEN DATEPART(hh, c.TRAN_DATE) <= DATEPART(hh,f.CUT_OFF_TIME) THEN c.NET_PAYMENT ELSE 0 END AS Net_Before_CutOff, 
CASE WHEN DATEPART(hh, c.TRAN_DATE) > DATEPART(hh,f.CUT_OFF_TIME) THEN c.DISCOUNT_AMOUNT ELSE 0 END AS Discount, 
CASE WHEN DATEPART(hh, c.TRAN_DATE) <= DATEPART(hh,f.CUT_OFF_TIME) THEN c.DISCOUNT_AMOUNT ELSE 0 END AS Discount_Before_CutOff,
CASE WHEN DATEPART(hh, c.TRAN_DATE) > DATEPART(hh, f.CUT_OFF_TIME) THEN d.USER_DEF8 ELSE 0 END As AdditionalCommission, 
CASE WHEN DATEPART(hh, c.TRAN_DATE) <= DATEPART(hh, f.CUT_OFF_TIME) THEN d.USER_DEF8 ELSE 0 END As AdditionalCommission_Before_CutOff, 
c.REMARKS AS Remark, c.USER_STAMP AS UserStamp,CAST(DATEADD(hh, - DATEPART(hh, f.CUT_OFF_TIME), c.TRAN_DATE) AS DATE) AS BusinessDay, 
c.TRAN_DATE AS TranDate, e.BRANCH_ID AS BranchID, d.STAFF_CODE AS StaffCode, c.ISACTIVE AS IsActive
FROM SC_TRAN_HEADER AS c 
INNER JOIN SC_TRAN_DETAIL AS d ON d.INTERNAL_TRAN_NUM = c.INTERNAL_TRAN_NUM 
INNER JOIN SC_BRANCH AS e ON c.BRANCH_NUM = e.INTERNAL_NUM 
INNER JOIN SC_COMMISSION AS f ON f.BRANCH_NUM = c.BRANCH_NUM) AS TMP
```

Comment: What is your question?  The query does not produce the results that you intend, although you say that it does.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff The query above is incomplete but I intend to produce the output as above. Do you know how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best that I can come up with, based on the information in your question, is:

```
with cte as (<your query here>)
select branchid, sum(sale) as payment, sum(discount) as discount,
       sum(sale) - sum(discount)
from cte
group by branchid;
```

If this is not correct, then edit your question to provide more information to help resolve your question.

Answer (score 0):

FIRST, I would try to simplify the readability of this query from all the case/when conditions.  First, you do case/when in your preliminary query on repeated tests to get before and after cut-off period, then others you do based on withdrawal or NOT withdrawal and yet again for Active vs Not Active.

Simple math multipliers... consider your query segment... your inner query to get the values of Sale and Sale_Before_CutOff.

```
CASE WHEN DATEPART(hh,c.TRAN_DATE) > DATEPART(hh, f.CUT_OFF_TIME) THEN c.TOTAL_PAYMENT ELSE 0 END AS Sale, 
CASE WHEN DATEPART(hh, c.TRAN_DATE)<= DATEPART(hh, f.CUT_OFF_TIME) THEN c.TOTAL_PAYMENT ELSE 0 END AS Sale_Before_CutOff,
```

Both test the date part for the cutoff time, and the answer can be Before, or After, never both. You do the same tests for Net, Net_Before_Cutoff, Withdrawal, Withdrawal_Before_Cutoff.

```
CASE WHEN PaymentType='Withdrawal' THEN 0 ELSE (CASE WHEN IsActive='N' THEN 0 ELSE Net END) END As Net ,
CASE WHEN PaymentType='Withdrawal' THEN 0 ELSE (CASE WHEN IsActive='N' THEN 0 ELSE Net_Before_CutOff END) END As Net_Before_CutOff ,
CASE WHEN PaymentType='Withdrawal' THEN Net ELSE 0 END As Withdrawal, 
CASE WHEN PaymentType='Withdrawal' THEN Net_Before_CutOff ELSE 0 END As Withdrawal_Before_CutOff,
```

THEN, in your main part of the query, you are applying yet again a nested case/when(case/when)

```
CASE WHEN PaymentType='Withdrawal' THEN 0 ELSE (CASE WHEN IsActive='N' THEN 0 ELSE Sale END) END As Sale ,
CASE WHEN PaymentType='Withdrawal' THEN 0 ELSE (CASE WHEN IsActive='N' THEN 0 ELSE Sale_Before_CutOff END) END As Sale_Before_CutOff ,
CASE WHEN PaymentType='Withdrawal' THEN 0 ELSE (CASE WHEN IsActive='N' THEN 0 ELSE Net END) END As Net ,
CASE WHEN PaymentType='Withdrawal' THEN 0 ELSE (CASE WHEN IsActive='N' THEN 0 ELSE Net_Before_CutOff END) END As Net_Before_CutOff ,
CASE WHEN PaymentType='Withdrawal' THEN Net ELSE 0 END As Withdrawal, 
CASE WHEN PaymentType='Withdrawal' THEN Net_Before_CutOff ELSE 0 END As Withdrawal_Before_CutOff,
```

What I would do, is from your subquery qualifying records, I would get the raw amount columns and 6 flags to act as multiplers.

```
SELECT ...
      c.TOTAL_PAYMENT,
      c.Net_Payment,
      c.Discount_Amount,
      CASE WHEN DATEPART(hh,c.TRAN_DATE) > DATEPART(hh, f.CUT_OFF_TIME) 
         THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as AfterMult,
      CASE WHEN DATEPART(hh,c.TRAN_DATE) > DATEPART(hh, f.CUT_OFF_TIME) 
         THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as BeforeMult,
      CASE WHEN c.PaymentType='Withdrawal' 
         THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as WithdrawalMult,
      CASE WHEN c.PaymentType='Withdrawal' 
         THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as NotAWithdrawalMult,
      CASE WHEN c.IsActive='N'
         THEN 1 ELSE 0 END As NotActiveMult,
      CASE WHEN c.IsActive='N'
         THEN 0 ELSE 1 END As ActiveMult, ...
```

Notice, the same condition is applied to both parts, only the THEN/ELSE swaps the multiplier from a 1 to 0 respectively to what it should represent. So, for any given record, example result would be

```
Total_Payment   Net_Payment   Discount_Amount   AfterMult  BeforeMult  WithdrawalMult  NotAWithdrawalMult  NotActiveMult  ActiveMult
  100           86            14                1          0           1               0                   0              1
  200           170           30                0          1           0               1                   1              0
```

Now, simple thoughts... if you want to know how much total payments were before a cutoff and were NOT withdrawls, in your upper query it would be

```
Total_Payment * BeforeMult * NotAWithdrawal = TotalPayments_BeforeCutoff
```

vs payments AFTER cutoff

```
Total_Payment * AfterMult * NotAWithdrawal = TotalPayments_BeforeCutoff
```

Similar consideration for your Active vs Not active.  Use that multiplier, no sense in doing nested cases when you already have determined its status when pulling the records.   Lets take a look at your "Sale" column... The inner query getting the record is using the "Total_Payment" field

```
CASE WHEN DATEPART(hh,c.TRAN_DATE) > DATEPART(hh, f.CUT_OFF_TIME) THEN c.TOTAL_PAYMENT ELSE 0 END AS Sale,
```

then in the upper is a nested case/when.

```
CASE WHEN PaymentType='Withdrawal' THEN 0 ELSE (CASE WHEN IsActive='N' THEN 0 ELSE Sale END) END As Sale ,
```

The only time you care about the sale amount is when it is AFTER the cutoff, is NOT a withdrawal and when it IS Active, so just multiply those flags

```
Total_Payment * AfterMult * NotAWithdrawalMult * ActiveMult as Sale
Total_Payment * BeforeMult * NotAWithdrawalMult * ActiveMult as Sale_Before_Cutoff
```

Finally, you have so many other columns in the table being pulled and not used, why keep them.  And for what you are trying to get the SUM() of, its going to be much easier to read it something like

```
SUM( Total_Payment * AfterMult * NotAWithdrawalMult * ActiveMult ) as TotalSale
SUM( Total_Payment * BeforeMult * NotAWithdrawalMult * ActiveMult ) as TotalSale_Before_Cutoff
```

All that being said, I offer you this...  please confirm context, but should make sense from above.  Also, note, the last 3 column I added were the final total you are probably looking for where the summation did not care as to before or after the time cutoff... just the fact it was a valid payment/discount/net, was Active, and on two of them was NOT a withdrawal... Seeing this, you would need to confirm its accuracy.  The first 6 summations show based on respective after cutoff (no column name suffix) vs BEFORE the cutoff (column name HAS the suffix)

```
SELECT
      PQ.Branch_Name,   <-- CONFIRM COLUMN FROM PreQuery (PQ alias)
      SUM( PQ.Total_Payment * PQ.AfterMult * PQ.NotAWithdrawalMult * PQ.ActiveMult ) as TotalSale,
      SUM( PQ.Total_Payment * PQ.BeforeMult * PQ.NotAWithdrawalMult * PQ.ActiveMult ) as TotalSale_BeforeCutoff,
      SUM( PQ.Discount_Amount * PQ.AfterMult * PQ.ActiveMult ) as TotalDiscount,
      SUM( PQ.Discount_Amount * PQ.BeforeMult * PQ.ActiveMult ) as TotalDiscount_BeforeCutoff,
      SUM( PQ.Net_Payment * PQ.AfterMult * PQ.NotAWithdrawalMult * PQ.ActiveMult ) as Net,
      SUM( PQ.Net_Payment * PQ.BeforeMult * PQ.NotAWithdrawalMult * PQ.ActiveMult ) as Net_BeforeCutoff,
      SUM( PQ.Total_Payment * PQ.NotAWithdrawalMult * PQ.ActiveMult ) as TotalSaleAll,
      SUM( PQ.Discount_Amount * PQ.ActiveMult ) as TotalDiscountAll,
      SUM( PQ.Net_Payment * PQ.NotAWithdrawalMult * PQ.ActiveMult ) as NetAll
   from
      ( select
              e.Branch_Name,   <-- GUESSING ON THIS COLUMN FOR ACTUAL BRANCH
              c.Total_Payment,
              c.Net_Payment,
              c.Discount_Amount,
              CASE WHEN DATEPART(hh,c.TRAN_DATE) > DATEPART(hh, f.CUT_OFF_TIME) 
                 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as AfterMult,
              CASE WHEN DATEPART(hh,c.TRAN_DATE) > DATEPART(hh, f.CUT_OFF_TIME) 
                 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as BeforeMult,
              CASE WHEN c.PaymentType='Withdrawal' 
                 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as WithdrawalMult,
              CASE WHEN c.PaymentType='Withdrawal' 
                 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as NotAWithdrawalMult,
              CASE WHEN c.IsActive='N'
                 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END As NotActiveMult,
              CASE WHEN c.IsActive='N'
                 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END As ActiveMult
           FROM 
              SC_TRAN_HEADER AS c 
                 INNER JOIN SC_TRAN_DETAIL AS d 
                    ON c.INTERNAL_TRAN_NUM = d.INTERNAL_TRAN_NUM
                 INNER JOIN SC_BRANCH AS e 
                    ON c.BRANCH_NUM = e.INTERNAL_NUM 
                 INNER JOIN SC_COMMISSION AS f 
                    ON c.BRANCH_NUM = f.BRANCH_NUM ) AS PQ
   group by
      PQ.Branch_Name    <--  AGAIN, confirm column name here
```